# Function that takes in unknown datatype c

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I am implementing a sort of a linked list, where each node has a key, a value, and the next node. I have a function called `getVal`, which should take in a key, and a linked list, that returns the value corresponding to that key. The thing is, I don't know the datatype of the key, or the value. To combat that, I also pass a compare function, which I will use when checking each nodee. My current function signature is this:

```c
void* getVal(node *list, void *key, int (*compare)(const void *, const void*)){
```

The problem, with this, is that when I try to call this function with a string, for example
getVal(list,"test",strcmp);
Which should get the key "test", it gives a warning that the pointer types are incompatible. What can I do?

Comment: Can't identify the problem just by the single line of code. Can you show the whole function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the *expression* `strcmp` is `int (*)(const char *, const char *)`, which is *not* compatible with `int (*)(const void *, const void *)`.

You'll have to write your own routine which takes two `const void *` parameters and then calls `strcmp` internally:

```
int my_strcmp( const void *s1, const void *s2 )
{
  const char *ls1 = s1;
  const char *ls2 = s2;

  return strcmp( ls1, ls2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `const void* key` instead of `void* key` if the function `getVal` won't modify what is pointed at by `key`.

Comment: How will that solve my problem? My problem is with the compare function